# How to add more lights and sirens to motion detector

Tags: detector, motion, security, siren

I have a motion detector size of a cigarette box that rings bell or simple song when activated using a small remote control.  We turn it on after closing the business to go home.  We've had many window broken burglary.  I want to keep thieves hanging out by the windows and door at night time.
I was wondering if I can add a LED light strip, flood light, or may be even a flashing siren lights to this little cute motion detector.  So it can draw attention when thieves come by and hopefully bright lights will turn them away.  I'm thinking would the relay from cars work in this case?  I don't think adding led lights to the small motion detector will have enough power.  I really want to add extra lighting and horns to this existing motion detector, because it is set up for perfect area coverage and sensitivity.  Also I need remote control on and off. Thanks.

Comment: most likely, it is possible, but without knowing anything about this detector, it's not possible to say how to do it. Have you considered getting a proper alarm system installed professionally?

Comment: All switches of any type have activation power and contact power rating so there isgain in function. You can do anything you want with this in mind.  Driver to coil to contact rating. Diode clamps are used for turn off spikes